# Reading and updating OpenXML in F#

Tags: f#

I can't get this F# code to read and update Content Control text fields inside Word documents.
The second function does absolutely nothing and the first one produces this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Additional information: Sequence contains no elements

```
namespace OpenXML

open DocumentFormat.OpenXml
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
open System.Linq
// Add the DocumentFormat.OpenXml assembly
// Add the WindowsBase assembly

module public Word =

    let query_plain_text_content_control document_path_and_file_name content_control_tag =
        use theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open((document_path_and_file_name :string), true)
        let mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart
        let block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(fun r -> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val = content_control_tag).Single()
        let t = block.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault()
        t.Text

    let update_plain_text_content_control document_path_and_file_name content_control_tag new_text = async {
        use theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open((document_path_and_file_name :string), true)
        let mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart
        let block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(fun r -> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val = content_control_tag).Single()
        let t = block.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault()
        t.Text <- new_text
        mainPart.Document.Save() |> ignore
    }
```

Comment: When I said this was probably a new question, you shuold have rolled back the old question as this is now a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine, with a couple of tweaks:

```
#r@"DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll"
#r"WindowsBase.dll"
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
open System.Linq
// Add the DocumentFormat.OpenXml assembly
// Add the WindowsBase assembly

module public Word =

    let query_plain_text_content_control document_path_and_file_name content_control_tag =
        use theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open((document_path_and_file_name :string), true)
        let mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart
        let block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(fun r -> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.ToString() = content_control_tag).Single()
        let t = block.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault()
        t.Text

    let update_plain_text_content_control document_path_and_file_name content_control_tag new_text = async {
        use theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open((document_path_and_file_name :string), true)
        let mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart
        let block = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().Where(fun r -> r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.ToString() = content_control_tag).Single()
        let t = block.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault()
        t.Text <- new_text
        mainPart.Document.Save() |> ignore
    }
    let oldtext = query_plain_text_content_control @".\text.docx" "ctrltag"

    let update = update_plain_text_content_control @".\text.docx" "ctrltag" "new text"
    Async.RunSynchronously(update)
    let newtext = query_plain_text_content_control @".\text.docx" "ctrltag"
```

.. on a document containing a single plaintext content control, with tag of 'ctrltag', with content 'old text', I get:

```
val oldtext : string = "Old text"
val update : Async<unit>
val newtext : string = "new text"
```

Without calling .ToString() on 'r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild().Val', I got this error:

```
The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'StringValue'.
```

Perhaps there is a problem with your document? The error you are getting would seem to suggest that there are no content controls with the specified Tag.